# Fix and normalize weird data from internet

Tags: java, web-crawler

I did a web-crawler that download much pages and now I need to process the data it downloaded.

The problem is I data from much pages with all type of formatting and errors.

I want to be able to fix some wrong encodings, remove all non-printable characters and replace some chars with others (example: there a lot of quote chars. I want to replace with the common ").

There a lot of things to do. What I want to know is if there is a library or something done I can use or I need my solution for my needs.

Comment: Regular expressions are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already did some crawling but I still recommend that you make sure to store data with correct encoding when you crawl. Otherwise data can get lost before processing it.

For character replacement I would write my own utility class with smaller testable filter methods that use regexp internally. These methods should have there own test cases to ensure they work as intended.

Comment: What I trying to do now is fixing wrong data that came from internet before it goes to database. I'm storing data as UTF8 in PostgreSQL and it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Tidy can help (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or Jsoup (http://jsoup.org/)

You can formalize it to correct format (DOM) by Tidy or Jsoup.

PS: I am a bit more prefer in Jsoup.